# How can I get a string of bytes ( Hexadecimal ) from a regular string keeping exactly the same format?

Tags: python, hex, pyserial

Let me explain the question.

I have a script that communicates with a RFID reader using PySerial. When I define directly a variable with the hexadecimal instruction for the RFID reader everything just works fine.

e.g.

This is what I send to the RFID reader using PySerial

```
RFID_READ_TAG1 = '\xFF\xFF\xFD\x3F\x11\x83\x01\x10\x00\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\xB3\x71\xFE'
```

Checking the type and the value of the variable

```
print type(RFID_READ_TAG1), RFID_READ_TAG1
```

Returns this --> type 'str'  `���?�000000000002(C�`
this is correct :)

Now I am trying to make the code a bit more flexible using a string I have in a database and trying to build the code to send to the RFID reader:

Initial String

```
SNR = 'FFFFFD3F1183011000303030303030B371FE'
```

Every 2 characters insert \x (just works with double slash )

```
Builded_String = '\\x' + '\\x'.join([SNR[i:i+2] for i in xrange(0, len(SNR), 2)])
```

Check the type and value of the variable

```
print type(output),output
```

Returns this --> type 'str' `\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x31`
WRONG!!!

My question is, How can I do to get the same output than in the first example? or how can I convert a string to string of bytes ( hexadecimal ) keeping exactly the same values?

I have been struggling with this too much, please help!

If there is something I can clarify please let me know.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str.decode('hex')` and `str.encode('hex')`:

```
>>> RFID_READ_TAG1 = '\xFF\xFF\xFD\x3F\x11\x83\x01\x10\x00\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\xB3\x71\xFE'
>>> SNR = RFID_READ_TAG1.encode('hex').upper()
>>> SNR
'FFFFFD3F1183011000303030303030B371FE'
>>> SNR.decode('hex')
'\xff\xff\xfd?\x11\x83\x01\x10\x00000000\xb3q\xfe'
>>> SNR.decode('hex') == RFID_READ_TAG1
True
```

Comment: nice answer :) ... didnt even think about using decode hex for my solution :)

Comment: Worked like a charm! I owe you one! :)

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do what you are trying to do with the joining ... you probably are just gettnig bytes back try

`print repr(RFID_READ_TAG1)`

or

```
print  " ".join([hex(ord(c)) for c in RFID_READ_TAG1])
```

for changing this `SNR = 'FFFFFD3F1183011000303030303030B371FE'`

try

```
SNR = 'FFFFFD3F1183011000303030303030B371FE'
encoded= "".join([unichr(int(SNR[i:i+2],16)) for i in range(0,len(SNR),2)])
print repr(encoded)
```